# Foundation 5 - Dropdown button opening but not closing

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 5 on a static website. I used the index page provided with Foundation as my starting point, which pulls in jQuery and all of the Foundation JS just before the closing body tag. I haven't modified or added any Javascript myself.

My dropdown button opens up correctly, but it doesn't close if it is clicked (or tapped) a second time.  It only closes if I click (or tap) outside of the menu button, or if I click a link from the menu.  The behavior is the same across browsers on my laptop, iPhone, and Android tablet.

When I visit  [Foundation's documentation,](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown_buttons.html)  the sample buttons toggle as expected.  I tried copying and pasting their sample code into my web page, but it doesn't toggle then.

I tried asking on Foundation's forum, but the one answer I received wasn't helpful. My code and a screenshot are still  [there,](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2032-dropdown-button-not-toggling)  though.  There's also a newer post from someone else who seems to be having the same problem.

I saw a couple of articles that advised adding this before the closing body tag to initialize the Foundation JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

I gave it a shot, but it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: I had this issue with Foundation 4 and had to build a workaround to get the menus to close when link is clicked. I managed to make it happen but now I've updated to Foundation 5 and am struggling to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found this and it seems to be working for me...

```
$(function() {
    $('li.has-dropdown a:not(.no-ajaxy)').click(function(evt) {
        $('.toggle-topbar').click();
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** The ":not(.no-ajaxy)" part is specific to my implementation. I ajax all links by default and apply the no-ajaxy class to links that should not result in an ajax call when clicked. In Foundation's top bar drop downs, that would include the links that result in another drop down tier.